# Spring Boot - Move Spring Security configuration into a library for reusability

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning about Spring Security and so far have successfully implemented it in my API and it is working.

I am using Spring Boot 2.4.x and I have a class below that sets whitelisted urls, configures `AutehenticationManagerBuilder` and `HttpSecurity`.

It configures `AutehenticationManagerBuilder` to authenticate against AD.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter {
  ...
  // configure HttpSecurity and AutehenticationManagerBuilder
}
```

I also have `AuthenticationFilter` which handles authentication and generates a required token (jwt), and `AuthorizationFilter` class which validates the token received in requests.

This is all working well.

**What I am trying to achieve?**

I now want to build another API, using Spring Boot.  I know, I could copy this same code from API-1 into API-2 and it will work.  But I want to build a library instead so I can just add dependency to this library in both APIs.  That way I can reuse it instead of copying it all over other APIs.

I know how to create a library in Spring Boot but I am new to Spring Security and wonder if simply moving the 3 classes above into a separate library will work.  I would expect it will but I have never tried it before.

I wonder if someone has tried to do same with Spring Security and if I can get some good tips or resources to look at little bit before proceeding to try it.

Comment: the problem with your solution is that you have included a filtar that already is included in spring security. Spring seccurity implements the resource server specificcation which already includes a filter that vill validate jwts. Im guessing you have followed poorly tutorials that tell you to implement a custom filter which only will pull in unneded external dependencies https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html and for an implementation https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  I will certainly do the read but so far from what I see it is Auth2 related which is not what I do.  But anyways, will read it.  For now, need to focus on asked question.

Comment: You are saying that you dont want to do ”oauth2” but still you have implemented a JWT filter that validates tokens and builds a principal. Which is exactly what the oauth2 specification does in the resource server part of the oauth2 rfc. You say you dont want oauth2 bit still you have implemented part of spec that spring security already have implemented for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it. It works. It’s the correct way to implement rather than copy and paste.

Just be careful to include the security package name in the `@SpringbootApplication` `scanBasePackages` because the package structure in the security library jar will probably not match the application structure

Imagine your security library packages are in `com.corporation.security` but your main spring boot applications class with the @SpringbootApplication annotation is in `com.corporation.app` then you need a SpringBootApplication annotation like this so the the security code in the lib is included.

```
@SpringbootApplication(scanBasePackages={“com.corporation.security”, “com.corporation.app”})
```